# Decomposition of the image of $\mathbb Z$ under a certain homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

While studying, I encountered a class of problems like the following:

Let $P=\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 3 & 5 \\ 4 & 9 & 25 \\ 8 & 27 & 125 \end{array}\right)$. Find integers $a,b,c$ such that $a|b|c$ and a basis $x_1,x_2,x_3$ of $\mathbb Z^3$ such that $P\mathbb Z^3 \cong \mathbb Z ax_1\oplus \mathbb Z bx_2 \oplus \mathbb Z cx_3$.

Now I know the structure theorem, and I know that if we do some matrix operations on $P$ we can get him to his Smith normal form which, If my calculations are correct, should be $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 30 \end{array}\right)$. But now my knowledge becomes a bit messy and I need some clarifications.

From what I understand, if we name $p:\mathbb Z^3\rightarrow \mathbb Z^3$ the homomorphism with matrix $P$ and given that this is the Smith normal form, we can choose new bases in $\mathbb Z^3$, such that $\mathbb Z^3 / Im(p) \cong (\mathbb Z^3 /\mathbb Z )\oplus (\mathbb Z/ 6\mathbb Z ) \oplus ( \mathbb Z / 30\mathbb Z)$. But I don't know what to do after this...

Comment: I think you have gone to far in your understanding. The calculation of Smith Normal Form says that up to change of basis in the target and the domain, $im(p) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus 6\mathbb{Z} \oplus 30\mathbb{Z}$ and then as a corollary you deduce the structure of the quotient $\mathbb{Z}^3/im(p)$.

Comment: @tkr: I wouldn't write equality. Both are subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^3$, but not equal ones, only (non-canonically) isomorphic.

Comment: "up to change of basis"

Answer (score 0):

You have done the problem. The integers are $1, 6, 30,$ while the vectors are the basis you get to conjugate to the SNF.